# jQuery selecting not disabled options when disabled="disabled" is used

Tags: jquery

Interesting one i've not dealt with before, usually if i have a disabled option:

```
<select><option value="test" disabled>Test</option></select>
```

I can do:

```
jQuery('select option:not(:disabled)')
```

But this doesn't work when it's disabled="disabled"

So how would the query look in this case?

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0k2Lvyh8/3/

Comment: Extended above fiddle for attribute `disabled` (without =) and using `:not([disabled])` - all return the same:  https://jsfiddle.net/sbrk3h0j/

Comment: that's so odd, it doesn't for me, it literally tries to select disabled ones , it's probably something else interfering somewhere

Comment: Yes, otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question :)   Can you add a snippet that *demonstrates* the issue?    [edit] and click `[<>]` and add your code (including script src=jquery, the html and your code)  (or use jsfiddle.net if you find that easier, snippet can be daunting at first)

Comment: Double-check for a space, eg: `('select option :not(:disabled)')`  (though that would select nothing)